Should I include H atom into C3N5 when i am doing DFT modelling?`
My experimental XPS analysis reveals that my C3N5 sample contains an N-H bond. Consequently, it is essential to incorporate the N-H bond into my DFT modeling to accurately reflect the experimental observations.
However, I do notice that several papers report an N-H bond in their XPS results but did not incorporate it into their modeling, while some did include the N-H bond.
This confuses me. Logically, I feel it should include the N-H bond so that the modeling is closer to the experimental case. However, is there any specific reason they omit the H-bond for modeling?
